# Looking for an old tv show featuring tiny caricature red haired boy with human blond girl

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I don't remember well the date, I guess it would be late 80's and early 90's.
The show was about a tiny caricature boy who had wild red hair and a blue overall. He was very naughty and got in trouble a lot. He was a caricature but the rest of the show was played by actors. there was a girl with blond hair and an old man who was her grandparent.

I remember two scenes, one, where the girl was in school and after break she had art class, but the tiny caricature boy got inside the classroom and used the art supplies.

Another one in which the girl put glue around the boy's tiny wooden bed to caught him. I think the boy could make himself invisible if he liked and the girl wanted to catch him. I remember the show being in Spanish, but I don't know if it was a translated version or if it was the original. Can't remember the boys name, but he was very peculiar looking, with fluffy red hair.

Answer (score 7):

Most of it sounds like [Pumuckl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumuckl), most likely the 80s TV show [Meister Eder und sein Pumuckl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meister_Eder_und_sein_Pumuckl_(TV_series)).

> The [elderly] master carpenter Eder meets the Klabauter Pumuckl, whom only Eder can see, because Pumuckl becomes invisible when other people approach. Pumuckl finally stays with Eder in his carpentry, and maintains a fatherly and friendly relationship with Eder.

Pumuckl is a sort of sprite or goblin but looks like a boy with wild red hair and is very mischevious. He becomes visible when stuck in glue. But he always wore green pants AFAIK, not blue overalls. Pumuckl was animated and the rest of the characters were live. Here's [Pumuckl](http://img06.deviantart.net/e0f0/i/2008/138/d/4/pumuckl_by_hermanmunster.jpg), and a clip:

Comment: Yes! this was it!! Thank you! 
I guess I was to young to remember the colour right xD

Comment: @EroFloppy No problem! :) Don't forget to click on the check mark to approve the answer.